# how do I use arraylist with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have it go through an array and assign values to it from an arraylist. I'm having trouble with trying to write a thing that can see if there are enough rows and columns for a set value in the arraylist names. everytime it prints it just prints as one line and not as row and columns with the respective numbers. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SeatingChart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // instanced variables
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int k = 0;
        String row = "";
        String column = "";
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (!name.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.print("Enter first name of student: ");
            // takes the name of kb and sets it to name
            name = kb.nextLine();
            // if the ArrayList names isEmpty then it adds the value at index
            if (names.isEmpty()) {
                names.add(name);
            } else if (name.compareTo(names.get(names.size() - 1)) > 0) {
                names.add(name);
            } else {
                // for loop going through the list of names to insert where it belongs
                for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                    if (name.compareTo(names.get(i)) < 0) {
                        names.add(i, name);
                        i = names.size();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (names.contains("quit")) {
                names.remove("quit");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names);
        // System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println("how many rows do you have: ");
        r = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("how many columns do you have: ");
        c = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Should students be seated row major(1) or column major(0)?");
        if (kb.nextInt() == 1) {
            // String arr[] = new String[names.size()];
            String[][] chart = new String[r][c];
            for (int i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < chart[0].length; j++) {
                    if (k < names.size()) {
                        chart[i][j] = names.get(k);
                        k += 1;
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%10s ", chart[i][j]);
                }
            }

        } else if (kb.nextInt() == 2) {
            String arr[] = new String[names.size()];
            String[][] chart = new String[r][c];
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                arr[i] = names.get(i);
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    arr[i] = chart[r][c];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < chart[0].length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < chart.length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%10s ", chart[i][j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Column order!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input

Comment: get assumption no of student from R*C and this should be less then or equal to list of student then only proceed to populate array. Printing task depend upon you how you want to look data at console and this will done with the help of combination of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed one ***IF Block*** for major

```
    if (kb.nextInt() == 1) {
        // String arr[] = new String[names.size()];
        String[][] chart = new String[r][c];
        for (int i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chart[0].length; j++) {
                if (k < names.size()) {
                    chart[i][j] = names.get(k);
                    k += 1;
                }
                System.out.printf("%10s ", chart[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println(""); // ADD THIS
        }

    }
```